# ClickOnce, XNA redist, and F# redist

Tags: xna, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application which includes its XNA and F# dependencies. Unfortunately, setup stops because XNA is not installed, which I expect should be solved by the installer itself.

I am hosting the application at Codeplex.

Comment: Oh come on, what about the implicit "How do I avoid that setup stops whining when the dependency is INCLUDED IN THE PACKAGE?"?

There, now you have two question marks in a row!

Comment: Well, firstly it's kind of obvious that you should ask a question more or less (preferably more) implicitly, secondly it's in your powers to edit the question after posting it, and thirdly a quick google search for "clickonce dependencies" gives some answers about removing prerequisites from ClickOnce compilation menu. You can always be rude to people, but eventually you will run out of those who wish to help.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce installs prerequisites as requested by you in the Prerequisites dialog. If XNA is not installed on the machine already, and you don't (a) provide the assemblies locally in the deployment, or (b) specify the components as prerequisites, it will not just go out and figure it out and install them "willy-nilly".